# Looping through multiple YAML files to find specific data

Tags: java, file, yaml, bukkit

I would like to just ask, how would one be able to loop through YAML files to find the needed data?

My situation: I have a Spigot/Bukkit server, and it has a folder filled with lots of files. What I'd need to do, is go through each of these files separately in the plugin to find which file contains the data I need. How could I achieve this?

Comment: What data is it that you want to find? If you give us an example we might be able to help.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Just a string value within the YAML. But I need to know how I could loop through a multitude of YAML files.

Comment: with a loop such as a for loop or a while loop

Comment: @Aequitas whatever gets the job done

Comment: could you elaborate please, could you show us your attempt? you haven't given enough info, if you're jsut asking how to loop through files it's simply `for(File file : fileCollection){readFile(file);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through Files by using:

```
YamlConfiguration config = new YamlConfiguration();
File[] files = this.getDataFolder().listFiles();
for(File file : files){
    try {
        config.load(file);
        if(config.contains("Path")){
            //What you need to do.
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

loading them and then cycling through loading them, and then checking if they contain the path you need. However, you may need to specify a folder, to do that simply do a statement within the for loop like:

```
file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "FOLDER_NAME");
```

But really that last part is incase you have other types of files. You can end up getting an exception if you aren't careful. In general what you are doing isn't generally necessary and there is most likely a much better solution. Just answering your question though.

Comment: Thank you! I realize there is probably a better solution, but I am on a deadline and need this quickly, so I may just upgrade it in the future.

Comment: No problem! I know how it is for us plugin developers.. :P

Although upgrade it later, when the time DOES come to upgrade, I think it may be along the lines of the person adding their file names to config.yml. If, of course, that fits your server employer's needs! If not, well this may be the best way for all I know. Normally I would just have configs that people can change, not configs people can MAKE. Interesting though
(Also, remember to accept any answer you decide is the best!)
finally, beware that if multiple contain the necessary path, it would do it for each file...

Comment: Yeah, I'll be working on checking through the data to make sure it's the file I want it to edit.